# Simplest way to perform operations involving adjacent elements in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have array, and I want to perform an operation that modifies an element's contents using two neighbor elements. I don't think the `map` operator is suitable. For example: operation that replaces two neighbor elements with average of them if `abs(element1-element2) <= 2`

```
my @arr = (0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 1, 1);
my @outarr = magic(@arr);
for(@outarr)
{
    print "$_ ";
}
```

And I want output to be: `0 5 9 1`

Is there a way to do this with the elegance of the `map` or `grep` operators?

Comment: No, I think Perl has many ways of doing one task, and I want to know the clever one.

Comment: I don't understand how the algorithm you describe results in `0, 5, 9, 1`. There are three pairs that are different by two or less: `(3,5)` (which should be replaced by `4`), `(5,6)` (which should be replaced by `5.5`, and `1,1` (which should be replaced by `1`). I think that leaves `0, 4, 5.5 9, 1`. How do you explain the result that you give?

Comment: (0,3)->(0, 3), (3,5)->(4), (4,6)->(5), (5,9)->(5,9), (9,1)->(9,1), (1,1)->1

Comment: No, (0, 3, 5, 6) becomes (0,5) and (9, 1, 1) becomes (9, 1) Substitution takes on place, so (0 ,3, 5, 6) -> (0, 3, 5, 6) -> (0, 4, 6) -> (0, 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through your array with a state variable to build your new array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = ( 0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 1, 1 );

my @outarr;
my $lastval;

for (@arr) {
    if ( !defined $lastval ) {
        $lastval = $_;
    } elsif ( abs( $lastval - $_ ) > 2 ) {
        push @outarr, $lastval;
        $lastval = $_;
    } else {
        $lastval = ( $lastval + $_ ) / 2;
    }
}

push @outarr, $lastval if defined $lastval;

print "@outarr\n";
```

Outputs:

```
0 5 9 1
```